# How to navigate to different screens based on the state in viewmodel with jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel, android-jetpack-navigation, kotlin-stateflow

I have an authentication module which contains `login`, `otp confirmation` among other screens. I have an `AuthViewModel` which handles UI events as below:

```
@HiltViewModel
class AuthViewModel @Inject constructor(private val repo: AuthRepository) : ViewModel() {
    private val _authState = MutableStateFlow(AuthState.UNAUTHENTICATED)
    val authState: StateFlow<AuthState> = _authState.asStateFlow()

    fun login(credential: Login) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            //.. call repo method here
            _authState.value = AuthState.OTP
         }
     }

     fun confirm(otp: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            //.. call repo method here
            _authState.value = AuthState.AUTHENTICATED
         }
     }
}
```

As you can see I update the `authState` to navigate to different screens when `login()` and `confirm()` are successful. However, I'm unable to observe the `authState` from a common composable function and trigger the navigation accordingly.

Here is my navigation graph looks like:

```
const val authRoute = "auth"
fun NavGraphBuilder.authNavigation(navController: NavController) {
    navigation(startDestination = loginRoute, route = authRoute) {
        composable(loginRoute) {
            val parentEntry = remember(it) { navController.getBackStackEntry(authRoute) }
            val vm: AuthViewModel = hiltViewModel(parentEntry)
            LoginScreen(vm, onOtpSent = {
                navController.navigate(otpRoute)
            })
        }

        composable(otpRoute) {
            val parentEntry = remember(it) { navController.getBackStackEntry(authRoute) }
            val vm: AuthViewModel = hiltViewModel(parentEntry)
            OtpScreen(vm, onAuthenticated = {
                navController.navigate(homeRoute)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Currently, I observe the `vm.authState` from each screen and then trigger callback lamdbda functions as below:

```
@Composable
fun LoginScreen(vm: AuthViewModel, onOtpSent: () -> Unit) {
    val authState = vm.authState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle().value
    val currentOnOtpSent = rememberUpdatedState(onOtpSent)

    LaunchedEffect(authState) {
        if (authState == AuthState.OTP) {
            currentOnOtpSent.value()
        }
    }

    val state = vm.loginUiState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle().value
    LoginUi(state, onLogin = vm::login)
}
```

However, the problem with this approach is that, when user presses the back button from the `OtpScreen`, the `LaunchedEffect` coroutine in the `LoginScreen` gets called again navigating back to the `OtpScreen` again instead of staying in the `LoginScreen` as the `authState` in viewmodel still contains navigate to `OTP` state. This is a likely issue if I were to observe the `authState` from all the composable routes instead of from just one place.

In the `View world` I used to solve this issue by only observing the `authState` in ViewModel from the Activity as a common place for all the Auth fragments and navigate to appropriate fragments based on the `authState`.

However, in the compose world, I can't find a common place to navigate between the auth screens based on the ViewModel state. How do I do that?

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Read this UI Events guide: https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture/ui-layer/events. Especially sections "Consuming events can trigger state updates" and "Navigation events" will help you.

Comment: Instead of navigating like this on the basis of state updates, you can create `NavManager` class which will contain navigation functions and inject it in ViewModel. And according to your need, just call NavManager's function to navigate

Comment: @Megh, Navigation is pretty much view's thing, I would not want my ViewModels to know about the navigation logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of experiments, I ended up doing as below as per the documentation provided here for [Navigation events](https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture/ui-layer/events#navigation-events)

```
@Composable
fun LoginScreen(vm: AuthViewModel, onOtpSent: () -> Unit, onRegister: () -> Unit) {
    val state = vm.loginUiState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle().value
    var isLoggingIn by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }

    LoginUi(
        state,
        onLogin = {
            isLoggingIn = true
            vm.login(it)
        },
        onRegister = onRegister
    )

    val lifecycle = LocalLifecycleOwner.current.lifecycle
    val currentOnOtpSent = rememberUpdatedState(onOtpSent).value

    if (isLoggingIn) {
        LaunchedEffect(vm, lifecycle) {
            snapshotFlow { vm.authState }
                .filter { it == AuthState.OTP }
                .flowWithLifecycle(lifecycle)
                .collect {
                    currentOnOtpSent()
                    isLoggingIn = false
                }
        }
    }
}
```

The issue here is you would still have to replicate this code throughout the authentication screens whereever you expect to have a navigation event from ViewModel.

The `isLoggingIn` state keeps track of the event that's triggered to potentially update the navigation state and the LaunchedEffect would only trigger when there is event triggered from UI (login, register etc). This prevents the issue with the back navigation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally sure whether I properly understood your question.
Have a look at the [`BackHandler`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/activity/compose/package-summary#BackHandler(kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Function0)) function. There, you could reset the `authState` value from the ViewModel accordingly:

```
@Composable
fun BackHandlerExample(vm: AuthViewModel) {
    BackHandler(enabled = true, onBack = {
        vm.setAuthState(AuthState.UNAUTHENTICATED);
    })
}
```

For a cleaner separation of concerns, it is a common approach with Jetpack Compose to pass a `onBack` function as a callback to a Composable.

```
@Composable
fun LoginScreen(vm: AuthViewModel, onOtpSent: () -> Unit, onBack: () -> Unit) {
    BackHandler(enabled = true, onBack = onBack)
}
```

Then, you could call the AuthViewModel setter function within the NavGraphBuilder.

```
composable(loginRoute) {
        val parentEntry = remember(it) { navController.getBackStackEntry(authRoute) }
        val vm: AuthViewModel = hiltViewModel(parentEntry)
        LoginScreen(
            vm, 
            onOtpSent = {
                Timber.d("OnOTPSent called")
                navController.navigate(otpRoute)
            },
            onBack = {
                vm.setAuthState(AuthState.UNAUTHENTICATED);
            })
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. But unfortunately, this doesn't work! I wanted the back navigations to work despite the `authState`.

Comment: You mentioned that the LoginScreen LaunchedEffect would always directly trigger navigation to the OTPScreen because of the `authState` value. By resetting the authState before going back, this behavior should no longer appear. What is missing in the approach I posted?

Comment: I was looking for a solution that would allow me to observe the authState changes outside `LoginScreen` and `OtpScreen` composables so that the navigation can be implemented just in one place rather than spread across the multiple screens. Appreicate the help though!

Comment: I see. I feel like Compose doesn't offer a clean way to solve this out of the box.